# 32 bit binary-to-decimal conversion

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I have this code to get from binary to decimal:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include <math.h>                                                                
#include <stdint.h>                                                              

int main() {                                                                     

   printf("%lld\n", binaryToDecimal(11110000111100001111000011110000));            
   return 1;                                                                            
}                                                                                
long long binaryToDecimal(long long binary) {                                          
      int power = 0;                                                        
      return binaryToDecimalHelper(binary, power);                             

}                                                                                

long long binaryToDecimalHelper(long long binary, int power) {                      
    if (binary != 0) {                                                       
            long long i = binary % (double)10;                                  
            return (i * pow(2, power))                     
                            + binaryToDecimalHelper(binary / 10, power + 1); 
    } else {                                                                 
            return 0;                                                        

    }                                                                        
}
```

It works fine for small values (up to 16 bits) , but for 32 bits (which is what I need) it just returns garbage.

Comment: I think `11110000111100001111000011110000` should be `0b11110000111100001111000011110000` if it's supposed to be binary.

Comment: Note that the above only works with GCC/Clang and will not compile on MSVC.

Comment: The code does not compiler with Clang. 11110000111100001111000011110000 is larger than the largest unsigned type (it would require a 104-bit integer :-)

Comment: `binaryToDecimalHelper()` should be declared before use.  This does not solve issue, but is one step.

Comment: Suspect you will have trouble values > 2^31-1.  Suggest doing this all with unsigned math.

Answer (score 3):

The number 11110000111100001111000011110000 is of type int, which can't hold a number as big as 11110000111100001111000011110000 in your machine. It's better to use a string representation instead ("11110000111100001111000011110000") and adjust your algorithm, if you can.

Comment: The problem is that I need to work at very low level. Therefore strings would too memory consuming. Bit logic would be best. Is there a way to just save the value as a sequence of bits, instead of a proper integer? (as using the 0b11110000.... format)

Comment: If you can explain what are you trying to do with more detail, maybe we can provide a better option. It isn't clear to me if you only want to convert binary number constants or if your number is some kind of input. Also, you can explain your memory constraints, because a small string like that isn't likely to be "too memory consuming" for most applications.

Comment: Note: "11110000111100001111000011110000 is of type int", though not quite correct, still does not work for OP.  Decimal constants like "11110000111100001111000011110000" become `int` or `long` or `long long` as needed and depends on machine.  In any case, it does not fit in OP's `long long`.

Comment: I will try to explain myself in a better way. I have a register which holds binary data in 32-bit. I need to retrieve that data and turn it into decimal to get the index of an array. Therefore the input to the function "binary to decimal" can be 32-bit long. I thought it would be memory consuming because turning from binary to string, and then to decimal would use memory and time that could otherwise be saved.

Comment: If you have 32 adjacent bits and you read the register as a uint32_t, I think that you already have your decimal number. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

if you are limited to 32 bits maximum this is one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void setStr(char *c, const char * x)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(x[i] != '\0')
    {
        c[i] = x[i];
        i++;
    }
}

void prepend(char* s, const char* t)
{
    size_t len = strlen(t);
    size_t i;
    memmove(s + len, s, strlen(s) + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        s[i] = t[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *x = malloc(33*sizeof(char));
    setStr(x, "111");
    while (strlen(x) < 31) // not really necessary, but will help to 'cut' bytes if necessary
    {
        prepend(x,"0");
    }
    printf("%s\n", x);
    int i = strtol(x,NULL,2);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `char *x = malloc(32 + 1);`

Comment: 32 ones as in "1111....111" may not work as desired with `strtol()`.  May need `strtoul()`.

Comment: well it will return -1. This is just a example of course. It can also be casted later to (unsigned long int).

Comment: On a 32-bit machine, I would expect `strtol("11111111111111111111111111111111", NULL, 2))` to return `2147483647` and set the `errno`.  Does yours return -1?

Comment: Yes it does... :) Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54668/discussion-between-chux-and-andro47).

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition - regardless of the actual width of a `char` which is given byte limits.h macro CHAR_BIT.  Though I am not sure why `malloc()` is needed in this example in any case - it just obfuscates what you are trying to demonstrate, as does all the rest of the code - it just needed one line surely? `printf( "%d\n", strtol( "1010101", 0, 2 ) ) ;`

Comment: @Clifford Assuming that the programmer may not be able to 'afford' the luxury of 'const char * smth = "11111"' I just wanted to demonstrate the possibility of dynamically assigning a certain value and expanding it to a constant width. I do however agree, that  printf( "%d\n", strtol( "1010101", 0, 2 ) ) ; would cover it all.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to be clear on is that your code does not convert anything to *decimal*, but rather to an *`int`*.  Conversion to a *decimal character string representation* of that integer is performed by the `printf()` call.

The literal constant 11110000111100001111000011110000 is interpreted by the compiler (or would be if it were not so large) as a decimal value, and as such will require 104 bits to store;

i.e. log10(11110000111100001111000011110000<sub>10</sub>) / log10(2<sub>10</sub>)

Representing a binary value with a decimal integer containing only 1 and 0 digits does not make much mathematical sense - though it may be convenient for small integers. A 64 bit `unsigned long long` is good for only 20 decimal digits (using just 1 and 0 - it can represent all 19 digit positive decimal integers, and some 20 digit values);

i.e. log10(2<sub>10</sub>) * 64<sub>10</sub>

If you need longer binary values, then you should probably use a string representation.  This is in fact simpler and more efficient in any case - you can use the fact that the machine representation of integers already is binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include <stdint.h>                                                              

uint64_t binstrToInt( const char* binstr ) 
{          
    uint64_t result = 0 ;
    int bit = 0; 
    while( binstr[bit] != '\0' )
    {
        if( binstr[bit] == '1' )
        {
            result |= 1 ;
        }

        bit++ ;
        if( binstr[bit] != '\0' )
        {
            result <<= 1 ;
        }
    }

    return result ;
}                                                                                

int main() 
{                                                                     
    printf("%llu\n", binstrToInt( "11110000111100001111000011110000" ) ) ;            

    return 0 ;                
}
```

Comment: +1 for correctly clearing the air here.  (Minor: suggest `uint64_t` and `PRIu64` OR `unsigned long long` and "%llu")

Answer (score 0):

This would be easiest by far with a string as input instead of an int, and would allow longer numbers. Your problem is probably being caused by integer overflow.

String version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    const char * const string_to_convert = "1010"
    int result = 0;

    for( int i = strlen(string_to_convert) - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
        if( string_to_convert[i] == '1' ) {
            // Careful with pow() -- returns double, may round incorrectly
            result += (int)pow( 10.0d, (double)i )
        }
    }

    fprintf( stdout, "%d", result );

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what the point of the `return 1` is. Usually a non-zero return value from main indicates an error.